# How to append to the end of a file?

Tags: vbscript

I need a program the will check a file for a string input from the user and if the string exists then display a message but if it does not exist then add it to the list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Dim strSearchFor
strSearchFor = inputbox("What is the url of the song?",,"")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("autoplaylist.txt", ForAppending)

do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 then
        Wscript.Echo "That song is already in the list."
    Else


        Wscript.Echo "That song was added to end of list."
    End If
loop
objTextFile.Close
```

But I'm not sure how to add text to the file.
Also it displays a message every single line, there are like 3000 lines. Is there any way to fix this too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this...

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim strSearchFor, strFileText, strFileName
strSearchFor = inputbox("What is the url of the song?",,"")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFileName = "autoplaylist.txt"

' Check file exists and ReadAll
' ------------------------------
If objFSO.FileExists(strFileName) Then
    On Error Resume Next

    With objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)
        strFileText = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "File access error"
        WScript.Quit
    End If

    On Error Goto 0
Else
    Wscript.Echo "File does not exists"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

' Search for input string
' If found append user input
' ----------------------------
If Instr(strFileText, strSearchFor) = 0 Then
    With objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForAppending)
        .WriteLine(strSearchFor)
        .Close
    End With
    Wscript.Echo strSearchFor & " was not found in " & strFileName & " and has been appended"
Else
    Wscript.Echo strSearchFor & " has been found in " & strFileName
End If

WScript.Quit
```